libusb_handle_events_timeout function continuously returning LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND in cpp
I'm using libusb on windows to work with multiple usb devices using default context.
For hot-plugin support I'm registering for the windows events not libusb.
I'm running infinite while loop in a separate thread function and inside the while loop i'm calling libusb_handle_events_timeout.
And i'm sleeping this thread for 5 seconds when libusb_handle_events_timeout returns anything less than LIBUSB_SUCCESS and continuing the while loop.
If any device is disconnected when any transfer in progress libusb_handle_events_timeout function continuously returns LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND.
Even after releasing interface and closing handle this issue is seen.
I'm not able to work with that device even after reconnecting.
How to resolve this issue ?
while (1)
{
            struct timeval tv = { 5, 0 };
            r = libusb_handle_events_timeout(NULL, &tv);

            if (r < LIBUSB_SUCCESS)
            {
                DDEBUG("ERROR: In Device Communication Thread. r = " << libusb_error_name(r));
            }
}

